# aws s3 ls - Bash script issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am executing a bash script that includes the following lines

```
source scl_source enable rh-python36
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$accessKey AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$secretKey aws s3 ls
```

When the second line of the code is executed with the bash script, I am getting the following error - An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the ListBuckets operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.

In order to troubleshoot, I used echo to output the command that is being executed. I copied and executed this echo'ed command, and the output is produced as desired.

Could someone tell what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the environment variables before the aws command:

```sh
source scl_source enable rh-python36
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$accessKey
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$secretKey 
aws s3 ls
```

Comment: As it happens a lot, minor mistakes are the toughest ones and waste the most time! In my case, the second command needed to be executed as an eval - eval ("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$accessKey AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$secretKey aws s3 ls")